# for in loop with key value pairs

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

I was trying for in loop to traverse through key value pairs :

```
a = {1, 2, 7, val4="val 4", val5="val 5", 9, "ten"}

print (a['val4'])
print (a[2])

print ("--- for in loop ---")
for k ,v in ipairs(a) do
  print (k,v)
end
```

output:

```
val 4
2
--- for in loop ---
1   1
2   2
3   7
4   9
5   ten
```

Can someone tell me why val4 and val5 was not retrived, what can I do to get them

hers the test in rpl.it: http://repl.it/Wzw/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ipairs` is used for sequences, it only iterates through integer keys from `1`, `2`, etc. But your table has non-integer keys like `"val4"` and `"val5"`. Use `pairs` instead:

```
for k ,v in pairs(a) do
  print (k,v)
end
```

Comment: That was ture, thakns